# ES6 copy properties to target only if they already exist

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Essentially what I want

```
let schema = {
       name: null,
       lastname: null
    }

let values = {
       name: "John",
       unwanted: "haxor"
    }
```

to end up in:

```
console.log(sanitized); // {name: "John", lastname: null}
```

--

Using `Object.assign(schema, values)` ends up with the unwanted value.

Is there a simple way?

Edit: I should add, this is to avoid using a library like lodash or underscore, so if the solution is overly complex, they would be preferable solutions.

Comment: just write a simple update routine. since you just need a shallow copy, you can fork an Object.assign polyfill, putting a conditional in the assign part.

Comment: You need shallow copy and only to support enumerable own properties that are not getters and/or setters?

Comment: Shallow copy is fine, not sure what you mean by value properties. (no prototype properties required if that's what you mean)

Comment: Been there. I'm not very fond of bringing the whole `lodash` to each and every project. But sanitizing is highly frequent task, so [`lodash.pick`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pick) module is definitely worth it, much better alternative to boilerplate loops. It's as simple as `let sanitized = _pick(values, Object.keys(schema))`.

Comment: @estus wouldn't that make `sanitized.lastname === undefined` instead of `null`? Also, it's `_.pick()`, not `_pick()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for noticing it, it should be `Object.assign({}, schema, _pick(values, Object.keys(schema)))`. `lodash.pick` exports a function, so it can be `import _pick from 'lodash.pick'` or whatever.

Comment: @EstusFlask needed slight tweek: Object.assign(resultdata, _pick(initialdata, Object.keys(resultdata)))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no builtin method which achieves that. However, there is a simple (almost trivial) way to do it:

```
const sanitized = {};
for (const p in schema)
    sanitized[p] = (p in object ? object : schema)[p];
```

Comment: Great, though I've updated the question, as this wouldn't handle the case where default values need to be copied from the schema object if they don't exist in the values object.

Comment: @Dan: Ah, I see, though so far none of the answers considered that. It's quite simple to add though :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update. This seems to be the most elegant solution. Through it I can conclude that the answer is in fact, probably a library is nice if this is done often. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Just retrieve the same key from the other object:

```
Object.keys(schema).forEach(key => schema[key] = (key in values ? values : schema)[key]);
```

If you want to create a new object:

```
var newObj = {};
Object.keys(schema).forEach(key => newObj[key] = (key in values ? values : schema)[key]);
```

Also, this is compatible with previous version of ES as well (if you do not use arrow function, of course).

The `(key in values ? values : schema)[key])` part assures properties that are only in first schema aren't set to `undefined`

Comment: @Bergi right, thanks. I see you already updated your answer, I update mine in same way just to have it working :)

Answer (score 2):

## Edited to OP's slightly more complicated request

Just `map` the value's and schema's keys to individual objects, and spread them. Prioritize `values` by placing them after:

```
Object.assign(
  schema,
  ...Object.keys(schema).map(
    (key) => ({[key]: schema[key]})
  ),
  ...Object.keys(schema).map(
    (key) => ({[key]: values[key]})
  )
);
```

If you don't want to overwrite `schema`, specify a different `target` for `Object.assign()`:

```
let sanitized = Object.assign(
  {},
  ...Object.keys(schema).map(
    (key) => ({[key]: schema[key]})
  ),
  ...Object.keys(schema).map(
    (key) => ({[key]: values[key]})
  )
);
```

Following a pattern closer to [@Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251189/1541563), you could do something less verbose like this with `Object.assign()`:

```
let sanitized = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(schema).map(
    (key) => ({[key]: (key in values ? values : schema)[key]})
  )
);
```

Comment: would a `const` be more syntactically correct for the last example? since you're not trying to overwrite the assignment, and that's what `const` prevents.

Comment: @Seth OP didn't specify if `sanitized` was supposed to be constant or not.

Comment: But the last example's point was to NOT overwrite schema's assignment. `let` inherently facilitates that possibility. `const`, by design, does not.

Comment: @Seth I think you misunderstood what I was saying. The first method assigns OP's `sanitized` object to `schema`. The second example does not touch `schema`, but assigns `sanitized` to a new separate object. There is no semantic that justifies `const` over `let` or vice versa.

Comment: Right, I understand your explanation... I was just merely commenting that assigning to a new empty object just seems like you may want to prevent that new assignment from being reassigned. And isn't the semantic justification of `const` vs `let` is to prevent reassignment, as mentioned?

Comment: @Seth the point was to prevent overwriting `schema`, not `sanitized`.